# Double integral equivalent to single integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

In Paul Nahin's book, *Dr. Euler's Fabulous Formula Cures Many Mathematical Ills*, he proves the irrationality of $\pi^2$ using the differentiation operator $\mathbf{D}$, its inverse $\mathbf{D}^{-1}$ and Euler's formula.

On page 98, he writes about $\mathbf{D}^{-2}$, letting $f(x) = \mathbf{D}^{-1} \phi(x) = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{x} \phi(s)ds$,

$$\mathbf{D}^{-2}\phi(x) = \mathbf{D}^{-1}\mathbf{D}^{-1}\phi(x) = \mathbf{D}^{-1}f(x) = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{x}\displaystyle \left\{\int_{0}^{t}\phi(s)ds\right\}dt$$

He explains how the region for integration is the following:
[image]

And so, he justifies that the double integral can be rewritten as,

$$\mathbf{D}^{-2}\phi(x) = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{x}\displaystyle \left\{\int_{s}^{x}\phi(s)dt\right\}ds = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{x} \phi(s)ds \displaystyle \int_{s}^{x} dt = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{x}\phi(s)(x-s)ds$$

I can't satisfactorily follow his explanation of the region of integration, and hence, the equivalence of the double and single integrals. Can somebody please explain it?

**Note** The pdf version of the book is available [here](https://www.pdfdrive.com/dr-eulers-fabulous-formula-cures-many-mathematical-ills-e156688400.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a change of order of integration. For simplification of integral draw the limits of integration $t=0,t=x,s=0$ and $s=t$ in $ts$ plane (which is your region of integration) and then change the order of integration. Actually firstly you are taking vertical strip $s=0$ to $s=t$ and then applying limits of $t$. But after change of order of integration you are taking horizontal strip $t=s$ to $t=x$ and then applying limits of s.